# Switched Language from English to Spanish but there are still english menus

Tags: samsung, 7.0-nougat, languages, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I purchased a phone for my Uncle and he doesn't speak English but the default language for the phone was English.

I set the Language & Input to Espanol, the Keyboard and Dictionary to Espanol and Google Now's search language to Espanol and 95% of the phone is now in Spanish.

The 5% left is is driving me nut though and I can't figure out how to reset it.  I thought maybe it was the Cache for Settings so I cleared the Setting App Cache, rebooted and no luck.  I tried to Delete Data for Settings App and that didn't work either.

Here are some images with examples of the mix of Spanish and English:
[image: Mix of languages]
[image: Another example]

Its driving me a little nuts.  Any ideas?

Samsung S6 Edge Stock with Android 7.0.

Thanks in advance.